# ElementTree: TypeError: argument of type 'Sentence' is not iterable

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to write a XML file but as I run `ET.dump(root)` I am getting:

```
<Reviews><Review rid="en_India'sGrill_477960693"><sentences><sentenceTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1078, in _escape_attrib
    if "&" in text:
TypeError: argument of type 'Sentence' is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/Data/workspaces/git/master-thesis/python/thesis/semeval/slot1/nlp_cnn.py", line 421, in <module>
    f.write(ET.dump(root))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1165, in dump
    elem.write(sys.stdout, encoding="unicode")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 775, in write
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 940, in _serialize_xml
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 940, in _serialize_xml
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 940, in _serialize_xml
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 932, in _serialize_xml
    v = _escape_attrib(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1090, in _escape_attrib
    _raise_serialization_error(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1056, in _raise_serialization_error
    "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)
TypeError: cannot serialize <thesis.semeval_data.Sentence object at 0x7f9087f20400> (type Sentence)
```

No idea what the problem is. I'm constructing this in a very straight forward way:

```
root = ET.Element("Reviews")
i = 0
for k in review_dict:

    review_element = ET.Element("Review")
    root.append(review_element)
    review_element.set("rid", k)

    sentences_element = ET.Element("sentences")
    review_element.append(sentences_element)

    sentence_dict = review_dict[k]

    for k in sentence_dict:

        sentence_element = ET.Element("sentence")
        sentence_element.set("id", k)
        sentences_element.append(sentence_element)

        sentence = sentence_dict[k]

        text_element = ET.Element("text")
        text_element.text = sentence.text
        sentences_element.append(text_element)

        opinions_element = ET.Element("Opinions")
        sentence_element.append(opinions_element)

        for category in aspect_categories[y_pred[i] > 0]:
            opinion_element = ET.Element("Opinion")
            opinion_element.set("category", category)
            opinions_element.append(opinion_element)

        i += 1

f = open(os.path.join(os.path.curdir, "..", "..", "pred.xml"), "w")

f.write(ET.dump(root)) # Exception
```

Any idea why I am getting this error? At first I thought it's because I didn't escape things but it appears that `xml.etree.ElementTree` does that already.

Comment: What is in `review_dict` and thus in `sentence_dict`? What is `sentence.text` in particular?

Comment: @schwobaseggl it's just a very lazy way for me to build the XML. `review_dict` maps a review-id to a `sentence_dict` which is just a map from a `sentence_id` to a `sentence` object. This `sentence' object is of type `Sentente` (the one from the error message.

Comment: it's something with the first sentence element, as it crashes right after `<sentences><sentence`

Comment: can you do `print(type(k))`?

Comment: Looks like it's either a bug in the library or you have malformed XML since the error occurs when the library attempts to serialize your XML.

Comment: Why use k twice better to use different names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at the traceback: `_escape_attrib()` raises a serialization error. Then refer to the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1075): ElementTree expects that element attribute value is a string and catches exceptions if it is not.

Check the type of values being used as `<sentence>` attributes: `sentence_element.set("id", k)`. One of them is not a string.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I made a mistake elsewhere that led to the wrong element being the key for the dictionary!